# Creating IXMLDOMnode from string

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, xmlnode

I have a string which contains the XML representation of an XML node which I intend to insert in a XML document loaded in memory. The XML string (of node)is something like this:

```
<ns1:Feature name=\"PageSize\">\
    <ns1:Option name=\"A4\" />\
 </ns1:Feature>
```

So, it has got namespace for the tag names as well.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

1. I tried to user `XMLDomNode->put_text()`, but it does not work as it replaces the "<" and ">" chars by their text representations (`&lt;` etc.)
2. I was wondering if loading the string buffer in a separate in-memory XML document and then getting the node pointer from there will work on my original document. But again, not sure if the XMLDOMnodes are transferable within documents.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself using the 2nd approach:

1) Create an in-memory xml document based on *IXMLDOMDocument3* interface and load the xml string in there.

2) Select the node you require using the *selectNode()* method.

3) Now go back to your orinial xml document where you want the node placed and load it again as a *IXMLDOMDocument3* interface.

4) Use the *importNode()* method of *IXMLDOMDocument3* from step 3 to clone the node obtained in step 2.

5) You can now use the cloned node to do an *appendChild()* to the original xml.